# Pushing LightningMessageChannel fails with "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, lightning-message-channel, source-push

I'm trying to create a custom LightningMessageChannel to use in my aura component. I followed the documentation and created a file for the message channel:

```
main/default/messageChannels/SampleMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml
```

The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>SampleMessageChannel</masterLabel>
    <description>Description</description>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>

    <lightningMessageFields>
        <description>Defines the type of record to create</description>
        <fieldName>entityApiName</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>

    <lightningMessageFields>
        <description>Defines the default values to use for the record</description>
        <fieldName>defaultFieldValues</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

Up next, I added the following to my aura component:

```
<lightning:messageChannel type="SampleMessageChannel__c" onMessage="{!c.handleMessage}" scope="APPLICATION" />
```

However, when trying to push this to my scratch org (`sfdx force:source:push`), it throws the following error:

```
ERROR running force:source:push:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```

When running the same command with the `--json` tag it gives the following details:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "TypeError",
  "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "Push",
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')\n    at /Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/source-deploy-retrieve/lib/src/resolve/treeContainers.js:165:37\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at Function.fromFilePaths (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/source-deploy-retrieve/lib/src/resolve/treeContainers.js:164:15)\n    at PushResultFormatter.componentsFromFilenames (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/lib/formatters/source/pushResultFormatter.js:169:129)\n    at PushResultFormatter.correctFileResponses (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/lib/formatters/source/pushResultFormatter.js:81:57)\n    at new PushResultFormatter (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/lib/formatters/source/pushResultFormatter.js:25:35)\n    at Push.formatResult (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/lib/commands/force/source/push.js:153:27)\n    at Push.run (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/lib/commands/force/source/push.js:32:21)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at async Push._run (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:81:40)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/sfdxError.js:171:27)\n    at Push.catch (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:248:67)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at async Push._run (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-source/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:85:13)\n    at async Config.runCommand (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js:173:24)\n    at async SfdxMain.run (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/main.js:27:9)\n    at async SfdxMain._run (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:43:20)\n    at async Object.run (/Users/user/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.154.0-1c265b4/dist/cli.js:162:47)",
  "warnings": []
}
```

Is this an issue with the SFDX CLI (`sfdx-cli/7.154.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.15.0`) or am I doing something wrong regarding the creation of the lighting message channel?

Comment: Hi Rink, based on [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/message_channel_create.htm) file name should follow this naming convention: `messageChannelName.messageChannel-meta.xml`, it seems like yours is missing the `-meta` before the `.xml` extension. also, could you post the content of that file?

Comment: Ah, I see I made a mistake while writing the question. This is the actual filename. I've edited the post.

Comment: Do you have the code that actually calls the push?  Normally "undefined (reading 'split')" would indicate to me that somewhere you have variable.split(...) but did not null-check the variable.

Comment: I use `sfdx force:source:push -u <targetusername> -f` to push the source to the scratch org.

Comment: Rink, could you post the content of the message Channel file? should be something similar to the examples found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningmessagechannel.htm)

Comment: I have added it to the question as well

Comment: it seems like a bug on your sfdx version, I just created and deployed both the messageChannel and an Aura component with the same source code you posted, and they were successfully deployed to a developer org. this is my sfdx version: `sfdx-cli/7.152.0 win32-x64 node-v16.15.0`

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue after downgrading to version `7.152.0`. It could potentially be an issue with me being on mac, as paths could be slightly different, causing the path splitting to crash. However, I do not have a windows machine to test this one. Any ideas on how to confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

When I deleted and recreated the scratch organization, I was able to push the lightning message channel to the organization.

I simply used `sfdc force:org:delete` and `sfdc force:org:create` for the recreation.

Before the recreation, I was not able to login to the organization anymore. Something must have corrupted it, but I'm unsure what.